# Netcobol cobol command reply "Argument is not valid"

Tags: x86, 64-bit, solaris, cobol, netcobol

On Solaris10 x86 64bit version, I installed Fujistu NetCobol, and executed "cobol" command. Result OS replies "Argument is not valid".

I used this cobol command, following the example in the [user's guide](http://www.netcobol.com/sites/default/files/documents/NetCOBUsersGuide.pdf).

```
$cobol -dy -M -o P1 P1.cob
```

Is there anything missing--some setting that I have overlooked?

I have confirmed the following:

- cobol with x authority
- cobol in PATH Environment variable
- Environment variable setting after NetCobol installing

Comment: Does the source file P1.cob exist, in the proper directory?  Do you have write permissions to that directory (so that you can create output files)?

Comment: Thank you to calibrate.Of course I have confirmed P1 exist and directory permission.

Comment: I tried removing argument one by one, but same reply.And only cobol too.

Comment: Seems like not a message from Cobol then, it doesn't even seem to be getting into the compiler.

Comment: I think so,too. Something is relevant to x86 or 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error often means you are trying to run a SPARC binary on an x86 system, which would make sense as Fujitsu produces SPARC servers.   To verify what platform the binary is for, run:

```
% file `which cobol`
```

(or `file /opt/something/bin/cobol` if you know the direct path to the binary.)

Comment: Thanks you for a good clue, @alanc.  
` % file ``which cobol`` `. 
reply "/opt/FJSVcbl/bin/cobol: ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped"
  
As @alanc said, this cobol is SPARC binary. Can't I use this cobol on my current environment?
  If I use or install something, I use SPARC binary On x86 OS ?

Comment: @user2236126: sorry, but there's no compatibility between SPARC & x86 CPU's, they use very different instruction sets.   You'll need to either get a version of the software built for x86 machines, or find a SPARC machine to run it on.

Comment: The manual you referenced covers SPARC. Does your installation software not match the manual?